# Achartengine Bar Chart : First bar overlaps y-axis

Tags: android, achartengine

i'm new to android and achartengine
I'm trying to create a bar chart and almost all things going well exept one
That is

My first bar is overlaping y-axis

```
  |
 _|_ 
| | |
| | |
| | |
| |_|_________________
```

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the X axis minimum visible value to something that will make the bar visible:

```
renderer.setXAxisMin(-0.5);
```

Comment: Wow!! That work good! Thanks brother you solved my big problem

Comment: facing the same isssue in line chart ... any suggestions ? @DanD.

Answer (score 0):

Because I do not have enough reputation, I can only give a new answer:

The approach from Dan did not worked for me, because the first bar is now
moved to far to the right. It is now not overlapping the y axis anymore,
but is ugly.
I just changed the method call to (minus to plus)

```
renderer.setXAxisMin(+0.5);
```